# Why do I get failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/releases...'" when deploying a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian

I'm deploying to a Debian 6 server, with Apache, Passenger, Ruby1.9.1

When I run "cap deploy" or "cap deploy:migrations" I get this error:

```
[out :: ip.address] Could not find multi_json-1.0.3 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: ip.address] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
 ** [out :: ip.address] 
    command finished in 1037ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/releases/20111208004427; true"
    servers: ["ip.address"]
    [ip.address] executing command
    command finished in 489ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/releases/20111208004427 && /usr/bin/rake1.9.1 RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on ip.address
```

Note the `run bundle install to install missing gems` and `failed sh -c ...` part.

I already tried this `export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:${PATH}` and tried many other possible solutions but nothing seems to work.

By the way, NO rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference for everybody else getting the same error. Found answer: http://www.pastbedti.me/2011/06/change-path-environment-with-rails-and-capistrano/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `config/deploy.rb` file is including Bundler's capistrano tasks with this line:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

This will tell it to run `bundle install` after updating your code, but before it runs other tasks like `rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: still getting this error: [out :: ip.address] sh: bundle: not found

Comment: You do need to log into your server and make sure bundler is installed before deploying:. If you're using a system-wide ruby (not rvm), then log into your server and run "sudo gem install bundler", then your deploy should work.

Comment: Already tried, then ran bundle in the command line and get command not found. When I do this `export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:${PATH}` bundle does work. So I added it to my .bashrc file of the user that deploys and cap deploy still get 'bundle not found error'. the deployment user only has ownership of its home file and the www folder.

Comment: I'm starting to think that sh its probably the problem and not bundler